How do I package another app with my own resource files?
I want to reutilize an app but add my own resource files to it.
"appToReutilize" is a uber JAR (aka fat JAR) except the resource files.
myApp's project has no code, just src/main/resources/*, a pom.xml and assembly.xml.
My goal is simple, when I build myApp I want 2 files:

appToReutilize-2.0.jar
resources.zip

I figured how to package my resources files into a zip using maven-assembly-plugin:
<groupId>com.me</groupId>
<artifactId>myApp</artifactId>
<version>1.0</version>

<dependencies>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>com.someone</groupId>
    <artifactId>appToReutilize</artifactId>
    <version>2.0</version>
  </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <descriptors>
                    <descriptor>assembly.xml</descriptor>
                </descriptors>
                <finalName>resources</finalName>
                <appendAssemblyId>false</appendAssemblyId>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>properties-config</id>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>single</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>

assembly.xml:
<assembly xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/ASSEMBLY/2.2.0"
          xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
          xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/ASSEMBLY/2.2.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/assembly-2.2.0.xsd">
    <id>properties-config</id>
    <formats>
        <format>zip</format>
    </formats>
    <includeBaseDirectory>false</includeBaseDirectory>
    <fileSets>
        <fileSet>
            <directory>${project.basedir}/src/main/resources</directory>
            <outputDirectory>./</outputDirectory>
            <includes>
                <include>*</include>
            </includes>
        </fileSet>
    </fileSets>
</assembly>

I read some more about this plugin and learned there's a way to package the app and the resources into a single jar but that's not what I need.
How do I solve this?

Solved using the maven-dependency-plugin!
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.3.0</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>copy</id>
            <phase>package</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>copy</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
    <configuration>
        <artifactItems>
            <artifactItem>
                <groupId>com.someone</groupId>
                <artifactId>appToReutilize</artifactId>
                <version>2.0</version>
                <overWrite>true</overWrite>
                <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}</outputDirectory>
                <destFileName>appToReutilize.jar</destFileName>
            </artifactItem>
        </artifactItems>
    </configuration>
</plugin>

